# Is it possible to overwrite a CSV file on a javascript event fired on the front end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, csv

I would like to know the feasibility of doing the following:

1. Fire a JavaScript event on the front end that changes a variable within a CSV (possibly by simply overwriting that file), then
2. Run a python script on the Django backend which reads that CSV and outputs to another CSV (my understanding is that AJAX works for this), then
3. Read the output with JavaScript and used on the front end.

Is this a possible event loop, particularly given the asynchronous issues presented? So far I've been able to accomplish step 3 using [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv), and I believe it's possible to run a python script with an AJAX call, making step 2 seem pretty doable. But is it possible to look into an input csv, grab a particular variable I want to change, and then change it?

Comment: It is certainly possible. You'd be best to use AJAX to send the request to Django to update the CSV file - just be ***very*** careful of file deadlocks/concurrency (ie. two users attempting to update the file at the same time). I'd suggest using a database of some description as it's far better suited to this than a CSV file.

Comment: I feel like I should probably know the answer to this (don't judge, I'm mostly a javascript guy!) - but how would you tell Django to update it? Not the specific code to do the update, that I can figure out, but how do you tell Django to "go do some work" based off of a front end event?

Comment: You can send an AJAX request to an endpoint you've defined. In jQuery, it's as simple as [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: Sorry again, but could you provide an example? I still don't know what this would look like in practice.